# Java System.out.println Prints 20 times

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter the size of the array:");
            String input = keyboard.next();

            int size = new Integer(input).intValue();
            int numbers[] = new int[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                numbers[i] = i;
                done = true;
                System.out.println("Good.");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException Error. Please enter a integer.");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error. Please enter 20 or higher.");
        } catch (NegativeArraySizeException ex) {
            System.out.println("NegativeArraySizeException Error. Please do not enter a negative.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I run this program it does not function properly. It should throw a exception unless I enter a INTEGER 20 or higher. However, it prints "Good." if I enter a number lower then 20. So if I enter 19 it will print "Good." 19 times. If I enter 3 it will print "Good." 3 times. I only want it to print "Good." if I enter 20 or higher. If not it should continue to loop through the exceptions.

Comment: My guess is that since `numbers` is never being used (only assigned values), the compiler simply optimized it away somewhere in your build process.

Comment: @TedHopp why would it only print out the value 3 times if he entered in 3?  That's what's confusing me.

Comment: new Integer(input).intValue();  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  numbers[i] = i; Your asking user for size but looping from 1-20? Can you write in steps what you want to do? also assigning  done = true; inside loop makes no sense. just once is fine after loop.

Comment: @MrTi - If the user enters 3, then the inner loop should execute successfully for `i` = 0, 1, and 2, but when `i == 3` the assignment `numbers[i] = i;` should throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` (since `numbers` is only 3 long). Apparently that exception isn't being thrown for OP (although it is for me).

Comment: @TedHopp Yeah, if it throws an exception, then it should only print 3 times.  But if the compiler simply optimized away the array, then it should have printed 20 times.  user2781647 what compiler/IDE are you using?

Comment: @MrTi - The title of the question indicates that it is, in fact, printing 20 times.

Comment: @TedHopp The title indicates that, but in the question he states if he enters 3 it prints "Good" 3 times. He is, in fact, getting expected behavior. It is just his program that doesn't do what  he wants it to.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an`Array` and `IndexOutOfBoundException`

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // < --- use (size) instead of constant 20 value
{
    System.out.println("Good.");
}
```

also add `finally block` with  `done = true;`

```
}  
finally
{
    done = true;
}
```

This will prevent the infinite loop throwing an exception.
Also add validation at the beginning of the program:

```
int size = new Integer(input).intValue(); 
if (size >= 20)  
{
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number more then 19");  
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, you need to check if number given number is less than 20 and throw the exception, that part of code is missing

```
import java.util.*;
public class ArrayExample {
private static Scanner keyboard;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter the size of the array:");
            String input = keyboard.next();

            int size = new Integer(input).intValue();
            int numbers[] = new int[size];
            if(size <20){
                throw new Exception("Number less than 20");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                numbers[i] = i;
                done = true;
                System.out.println("Good.");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException Error. Please enter a integer.");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error. Please enter 20 or higher.");
        } catch (NegativeArraySizeException ex) {
            System.out.println("NegativeArraySizeException Error. Please do not enter a negative.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand fully, but what I have got this program to do is if the number is less than 20, it will throw the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but if it is 20 or greater, it will print out "Good" for how many ever times the integer size was. I also changed the for loop into an enhanced for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Please enter the size of the array:");
            String input = keyboard.next();

            int size = new Integer(input).intValue();
            int numbers[] = new int[size];

            if(numbers.length >= 20) {
                for (int i : numbers) {
                    numbers[i] = i;
                    done = true;
                    System.out.println("Good.");
                }
            } else {
                throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error. Please enter 20 or higher.");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException Error. Please enter a integer.");
        } catch (NegativeArraySizeException ex) {
            System.out.println("NegativeArraySizeException Error. Please do not enter a negative.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to answer this is to just walk through the code and figure out exactly what is happening. For simplicity, let's say you enter three.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;  //ok so we set done to false
        while (!done) { //first time through, we are not done, so we enter the loop

            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter the size of the array:"); //you ask for a number 
                String input = keyboard.next(); //we put in '3'

                int size = new Integer(input).intValue(); //convert the input to an int
                int numbers[] = new int[size]; //we set the size to '3'

                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //we enter the loop, i is 0 so we continue
                    numbers[i] = i; //we set the value of idx 0 to 0
                    done = true; //we set done to true so we will exit the while loop
                    System.out.println("Good."); //we print good
                    //we increment i to 1
                }
                //EXPANDED LOOP FOR CLARITY
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //second time, i is now 1
                    numbers[i] = i; //we set the value of idx 1 to 1
                    done = true; //we set done to true again (kind of redundant)
                    System.out.println("Good."); //we print good
                    //we increment i to 2
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //third time, i is now 2
                    numbers[i] = i; //we set the value of idx 2 to 2
                    done = true; //we set done to true again (still kind of redundant)
                    System.out.println("Good."); //we print good
                    we increment i to 3
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //fourth time, i is now 3
                    numbers[i] = i; //at this point we should throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, so go to that catch statement
                    done = true; 
                    System.out.println("Good.");
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("NumberFormatException Error. Please enter a integer.");
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) { //so here we catch the AIOB exception
                System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error. Please enter 20 or higher."); //we print out an error, then continue
            } catch (NegativeArraySizeException ex) {
                System.out.println("NegativeArraySizeException Error. Please do not enter a negative.");
            }
            //here at the end of the block, we go back to check the while condition
            //we set done to true, so the while will fail and we will exit the program
        }
    }
}
```

Given that, your output should look like this:

```
Good
Good
Good
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Error. Please enter 20 or higher.
```

And that's all. The program will be done. Because you haven't posted the output, it would be difficult to debug this further.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines after `int size = new Integer(input).intValue();`

```
if(size<20)
throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("size is not equal to or greater than 20");
```

It will throw an Exception if the Size is less than 20. And no need to write those `try` and `catch` methods.

Hope this helped you...